# magento 2 css and js styles not working when accessed remotely but works internally

Tags: magento2

I setup magento 2.2.0 in developer mode to work via `dev.example.com` internally by setting up magento with nginx and then doing host overrides in the firewall. Everything works great locally.

Next i setup NAT in the firewall so that someone could hit the dev site remotely by going to `<publicIP:PORT>`. At first each time they visited the site remotely, it would try to redirect to `example.com` which of course we don't own so that didn't work. Next i went in the magento dev interface Stores>Configuration>Web>"Url Options" and set "auto-redirect to Base URL" to "NO". It was set to use system value which was "Yes 302 Found".

After making that change and doing a cache flush under "System>Cache Management", now external access from `<public IP:PORT>` is working and not redirecting, but css/js isn't working. There is no styling.

In the console I have

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            require.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            mixins.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            requirejs.config.js.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function            <publicIP>/:145 at <publicIP>/:145
```

All internal access is still working perfectly via `dev.example.com` for both admin and store front. It's just external that has this problem after making the above change to prevent a request from `<publicIP:PORT>` from redirecting to the domain since that domain only works internally.

After trying to flush the cache again I also have the following in the console with remote request in addition to the other error messages above:

```
Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://dev.example.com/?f"
```

Which tells me that the redirect setting i turned off doesn't apply to styles.

How do you correct the error above so that access remotely works via the IP and still has styling?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "auto-redirect to Base URL" back to the defaults and just set Stores>Configuration>Web>"Base Url" to `http://<publicIP:PORT>/` instead of `http://dev.example.com/`.

Flushed Magento Cache and everything's working internally and remotely.